# Yii2 $this->registerJs($js); How to pass php variable inside the $js

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Below is my ajax script in my view.

```
$js = <<< JS
    $('.list-link').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '?r=public/getlist&param1=01&param2=02&param3=03',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".well").html(data.id);                
            }
        })
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Now my problem is how am I going to make the values of param1, param2 and param3 dynamic like I am going to pass the params1 to 3 from php variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
$url = \yii\helpers\Url::to([
    'public/getlist', 
    'param1' => '01', 
    'param2' => '02', 
    'param3' => '03'
]);

$js = <<< JS
    $('.list-link').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".well").html(data.id);                
            }
        })
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Of course you can make the number of parameters dynamic as well since it is just an array that gets passed to [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail).

Official info about the used *Heredoc* (which allows variable usage) syntax can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Answer (score 1):

[robsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57091/robsch)'s  way is great (above answer).

But you can also do this way:

```
$js = <<< JS
    $('.list-link').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '?r=public/getlist&amp;param1=$one&amp;param2=$two&amp;param3=$three',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".well").html(data.id);                
            }
        })
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

where `$one`, `$two` and `$three` are PHP variables.

> And don't forgot to replace `&` with `&amp;` in Javascript text code
>   string above in `$js` variable in PHP. It is less error prone and good practice too

Comment: I think it's just fair to mark this also as correct. Thanks!