# Array to string conversion in registerJS - Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, yii2, data-conversion

In my view I have an array that I can reach by doing:

```
$model->stabilimenti;
```

Now in the same View, in registerJS I'm trying to save this array in a Javascript array, so I can add some clientside checks.

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    let jsArray = [];
    jsArray = $model->stabilimenti;

JS
);
```

With non-array variables this kind of approach works.

I've also tried to use this notation but without any success.

```
let jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($model->stabilimenti); ?>;
```

Is this a lecit operation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 $this->registerJs($js); How to pass php variable inside the $js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124829/yii2-this-registerjsjs-how-to-pass-php-variable-inside-the-js)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing braces and parenthesis `})` of the `.ready(function(){` function if that is not a typo pasting the code here.

You should parse the php array to javascript staying in php using `yii\helpers\JSON` or `json_encode` on the array `$model->stabilimenti` and convert it to json and then assign it to the javascript variable. and try loading the code at DOM ready, by using `\yii\web\View::POS_READY` when registering your script.

And you should keep the code separate from each other. See the below code it should work correctly

```
<?php
$stabilimenti = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($model->stabilimenti);

$js = <<<JS
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    let jsArray = {$stabilimenti};
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```